# CSS Position using center of element to position element using percentage

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

Hi so I was making a website and I just realized that it when I want to position the html element, it will position the element using the right side of it. Here's an example of what I mean. I was trying to position an image in the center using percentages. Trimmed down version of my css code: `.image{position:absolute;right:50%;`
So when I loaded the website, it shows up with the right corner of the picture at 50%, not the center of the image at 50%. Is there anyway to position using center of the image to position the picture at 50%, and not the left or right edge of the picture being at 50%? I don't want something like `position:absolue;right:45%` to move the picture over, but instead use the center of the picture to position the picture. If you need any more clarification just let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try the search option before you submit a question. This has been already asked (and answered) many times. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a width for the image and then set the left and right margins to auto.

```
` {width: whatever you want; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }  `
```

Comment: After I set the width and margins then do I set the position?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  If you want to keep it as absolute position, set that first, then add left:0; right:0; then add what I mentioned above.

Comment: Just tried it.. seems to work! Thanks! Heres the code I used: `.gold {
      background-image: url(../pics/emblems/Gold.jpg);
      width: 200px;
      left:0;
      right: 0;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;     
      }` The question I have is, what the left:0 and right:0 do?

Comment: One last thing, so suppose I want to position some html text at right:25%. Would the same method work for using the center to position the element?

Comment: Do you want the center of the text at 25%?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do it easily using `text-align`, when element you want to position is inside some container, i.e:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image">Center me!</div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .container { text-align: center }
    .image { display: inline-block }
```

2. Second approach: if you know the width of the element (`.image`). Let's say that it is 400px wide:

CSS

```
    .image {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }
```

A little bit tricky, can cause a problem when the width of the screen is lower than width of the element.

Comment: Thanks, but for the first one, I am using some text, so when I do text-align:center, it only centers the text relative to the image. Also, I forgot to mention but the image I am using is inserted using CSS `background-image:url(source)`.