# Position Element Using Center of Element?

Tags: html, css, position, flexbox, absolute

I am trying to make an element that has `position: absolute;` and is positioned using percentages. The thing is, it is not positioned using the center, rather, using the left corner. Is there a way to do this using pure CSS? The element is a flexbox, so there's no fancy tricks with the `display` CSS property. Here is my code.

```
#whateverDiv{
    display: flex;
    left: 25%; /* Uses left corner of element. I want to make it use the center of the element. */
}
```

Also, this is not a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946359/css-position-using-center-of-element-to-position-element-using-percentage) because the OP asked to center the element using percentage. I need to position it anywhere, such as `25%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using css transforms if that's fine

```
#whateverDiv{
    display: flex;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 'transform-origin' perhaps?.

```
div {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```